# Compute the minimum of the application $\displaystyle x\to \sum_{k=0}^n |x-k|$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

Compute the minimum of the application $\displaystyle x\to \sum_{k=0}^n |x-k|$.

**My attempt:** We know that : $\inf(A+B)= \inf A+\inf B,$ for two bounded sets in $\mathbb R.$ Let $S=\{S_n(x), x\in \mathbb R\},$
so $\inf S=\inf \{|x|, x\in \mathbb R\}+\inf \{|x-1|, x\in \mathbb R\}+\cdots+\inf \{|x|, x\in \mathbb R\}+\inf \{|x-n|, x\in \mathbb R\}=0+1+2+\cdots +n=n(n+1)/2=S_0.$ Then  $\inf S_n(x)=S_0.$

Is this approach true or not? any help please !

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543100/42969

Comment: The minimum is attained at $x = \text{median}\{0, 1, \dots, n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a different (and maybe shorter) solution than the ones in the link of Martin R.

**Case 1**: For $n$ even: $n = 2k$

$$\begin{align}
S(n)&:=\sum_{i=1}^{2k}|x-i|
=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(|x-i|  + |x - (2k+1-i)|\right) \\
&\ge \sum_{i=1}^{k}|(2k+1-i)-x - (x-i)| = \sum_{i=1}^{k}(2k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{2}
\end{align}$$
Then $$S(n) \ge \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{8}$$
The equality occurs $\Longleftrightarrow$ $(2k+1-i)-x = x-i$ for all $i=1,...,k$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x = \frac{n}{2} $.

**Case 2**: For $n$ odd: $n = 2k+1$

$$\begin{align}
S(n)&:=\sum_{i=1}^{2k+1}|x-i|
=|x-(k+1)|+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(|x-i|  + |x - (2k+2-i)|\right) \\
&\ge 0 + \sum_{i=1}^{k}|(2k+2-i)-x - (x-i)| = \sum_{i=1}^{k}(2k+2)=k(k+1)^2
\end{align}$$
Then $$S(n) \ge \frac{(n-1)(n+1)^2}{8}$$
The equality occurs $\Longleftrightarrow$ $(2k+2-i)-x = x-i$ for all $i=1,...,k$ and $x = k+1$  $\Longleftrightarrow$  $x = \frac{n+1}{2}$.